# How to set nREPL with Clojure CLI (tools.deps) & figwheel-main

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, figwheel

I want to use an nREPL server to connect from Emacs Cider with Clojure CLI (tools.deps, not Leiningen) & figwheel-main.
How do I set up my `deps.edn` or else?

---

I know there're nice examples for setups with Leingen&figwheel-main and tools.deps&figwheel-sidecar.

Leingen&figwheel-main: https://github.com/bhauman/lein-figwheel/wiki/Using-the-Figwheel-REPL-within-NRepl

tools.deps&figwheel-sidecar: https://functionalbytes.nl/clojure/nodejs/figwheel/repl/clojurescript/cli/2017/12/20/tools-deps-figwheel.html

---

This article (https://figwheel.org/docs/editor-integration.html) seems to for what I want to do, but I don't find how to set environment up in real.

Answer (score -1):

I have now done this and it is actually very easy. Both figwheel and cider have progressed a lot and figwheel-main is now a lot easier to setup. You can pretty much ignore most of the information in those links you have. To get going, do the following

1. Install clj-new from [here](https://github.com/seancorfield/clj-new). This will let you create a new figwheel-main project using the figwheel-main template, but as a CLI tools project e.g.

   clj -A:new figwheel-main hello-world.core -- --reagent

2.You now need to tell cider to run the fig alias when you start cider. There are a few ways to do this, but the quickest and easiest is to use a .dir-locals.el file in the root of your repository. Put the following in the file

```
((clojure-mode . ((cider-clojure-cli-global-options . "-A:fig"))))
```

You can also set this using customize-group or in your .init.el file, but doing so will set this for all your cider projects. Using the .dir-locals.el file allows you to have project specific settings.

Now all you need to do is open one of the cljs files in your project and enter

```
M-x cider-jack-in-cljs
```

When prompted for the reply type select figwheel-main and when asked for a build, enter :dev.

That is the basics. There are lots of other things you can do to automate and enhance things, but I'll leave that for you to discover. You might also fine the following useful

[CIDER Jack-in to Clojure CLI Projects From Spacemacs](http://jr0cket.co.uk/2019/07/CIDER-jack-in-to-Clojure-CLI-projects-from-Spacemacs.html)  - what the above is based on.

[figwheel-main + cli + cider](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hcFx-QL5ySM) - Video from Arne at Lambda Island, who I think does some excellent stuff.